# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array in single sub array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

my json is like

```
{
 "code":"1",
 "message":"The request succeeded",
"contacts":    
           { "contactId":"58330efb45cedb9087e281e6",
             "email":"",
             "firstName":"",
             "lastName":"",
             "number":"4145075733"
           }
}
```

and i am trying to use `DeserializeObject` with this `Generic.List`

```
public class AllContacts
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<ContactList> contacts { get; set; }
}
public class ContactList
{
    public string contactId { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

this is working fine with two or more data in contact array but it's not working in single data.

Error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (eg.{"name":"value"}) into
>   type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[smsApplication.Controller‌​s.ContactList]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly. To
>   fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array or change the
>   deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
>   primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
>   `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: please define "not working". You get an error message, or it doesn't produce the expected result? Give an example.

Comment: "Not working" gives error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (eg.{"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[smsApplication.Controllers.ContactList]' because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: Another approach, you could use JObject and SelectToken to pull in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `contact` is a json object and not a json array

Either update the json to match the defined classes

```
{
 "code":"1",
 "message":"The request succeeded",
"contacts":[    
           { "contactId":"58330efb45cedb9087e281e6",
             "email":"",
             "firstName":"",
             "lastName":"",
             "number":"4145075733"
           }]
}
```

Or update the classes to match the json

```
public class AllContacts
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public ContactList contacts { get; set; }
}

public class ContactList
{
    public string contactId { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

The error message explains what you do.